# Rails: Simple Form Association label_method from Grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, model-associations

I am trying to build a form that will create a new record using Simple Form, but I am having trouble showing the correct label in the dropdown list.  First, the relevant models:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_one :enrollment
  has_many :clients, through: :enrollment
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  has_one :enrollment
  has_many :services, through: :enrollment
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrollment
end
```

The basic idea is that a client will be enrolled in one or more services.  A job represents an appointment to perform the service.  When creating a new job, I need to select the enrollment that the job belongs to.  From the html.erb:

```
<%= f.association :enrollment, label_method: :service_id, value_method: :id, prompt: 'Choose an enrolled service' %>
```

This sort of works, but it only shows me the service_id from the Enrollment table.  What I want to see is the name of the Client (fname and lname) and the name of the Service concatenated in the dropdown list, like this: "John Doe: Window Washing".  The problem is that both of those come from the parents of Enrollments.  Basically I need to traverse two associations to get to the label that I want.

I thought about de-normalizing so that the Enrollment record has the data I need, but I'd rather not do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Enrollment class define following method:

```
def name
  "#{client.full_name}: #{service.name}"
end
```

Then you should be able to use this method in your form:

```
<%= f.association :enrollment, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: 'Choose an enrolled service' %>
```

To avoid 2*n+1 sql queries prepare enrollments collection with included clients and services.